# Two Timer Interrupts, One Incorrect?

Tags: interrupt, timers

I'm trying to replicate a waveform exactly using external and timing interrupts. I've got an external that's setup as a 0ms reference, TIMER1 which is used to determine on time, and TIMER2, which sets the low period. Unfortunately, I can't get the pin low for 2ms. TIMER2 must have something wrong with it, but I can't find it. Instead of banging my head against the wall, I thought I'd ask you guys. Anyone know the answer?

```
//3 is interrupt for Timing
//4 through 11 are Time dependent receivers
//3-11 Pins 12-19

//Current Serial Byte(Letter or Number)
char incomingByte = 0;
//Previous Byte in the Serial Chain
char previousByte = 0;

//Iterator for Interrupt Values
volatile unsigned int maincount = 0;

//Time of High Period or Timer Duration
volatile unsigned int timerhigh;

//Output Pin for Timer Waveform
volatile unsigned int waveout;

//Time for Timer Delay in milliseconds, default tim
volatile unsigned int groundtime = 0;

//Receiver Pins in an Array, except for 3, which serves as 0 source reference
int pins[9] =
{
  3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
};

void rising()
{   
  // set up Timer 1
  TCCR1A = 0;  // normal mode
  TCCR1B = bit(WGM12) | bit(CS11);  // CTC, scale to clock / 8
  OCR1A = timerhigh;          // time before timer fires
  TIMSK1 = bit (OCIE1A);            // interrupt on Compare A Match
}


//Sets Pin Low, then sets up another timer interrupt for the jump back to high
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
 //Brings Pin Low for Keypress
 //Serial.println("We're in Timer 1");
 pinMode(waveout,OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(waveout, LOW);

 //Stop Timer 1
 TCCR1B = 0;                      // stop timer
 TIMSK1 = 0;                      // cancel timer interrupt

 //Disables Interrupts Before Messing
 cli();
 // set up Timer 2
 TCCR2A = 0;  // normal mode
 TCCR2B = 0;
 //  TCCR2A = bit(WGM21) | bit(CS21);  // CTC, scale to clock / 8
 TCCR2A = (1 << WGM21); //Enables CTC for timer 
 TCCR2B = (1 << CS21); //Sets 8 bit prescaler
 OCR2A = groundtime;          // time before timer fires
 TIMSK2 = (1 << OCIE2A);

 //Cancel Rising Interrupt on D3
 EIFR = bit (INTF1); 
 //Reenables interrupts
 sei();
}

//Timer Interrupt for Low Period
ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect)
{
//Serial.println("WE'RE IN TIMER2");
//Brings Output pin high
digitalWrite(waveout, HIGH);

//Stop Timer 2
TCCR2B = 0;                      // stop timer
TIMSK2 = 0;                      // cancel timer interrupt  

//Cancel Rising Interrupt on D3
 EIFR = bit (INTF1);   
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

//Sets all the pins for output use
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
  pinMode(pins[i], INPUT);
}

//Sets Reference Pin as Input
pinMode(3,INPUT);


//Begins Serial
Serial.begin(115200);

//Cancels Timer 1
TCCR1A = 0;  // normal mode
TCCR1B = 0;  // stop timer
TIMSK1 = 0;   // cancel timer interrupt

//Cancels Timer 2
 TCCR2A = 0;
 TCCR2B = 0;                      // stop timer
 TIMSK2 = 0;                      // cancel timer interrupt  
detachInterrupt(1);

}

void loop() {

  //Time of Ground Drop(2 mS), Universal for all letters and offsets
  groundtime = 40000;     // spark time (4000 * 500 nS) = 2 mS

  // because of prescaler of 8, each unit is 500 nS (0.5 µS)

     if(Serial.available()> 0);
    {
   //Reads Serial Value and assigns to incomingByte
   incomingByte = Serial.read();
   attachInterrupt(1,rising,RISING);
    }
  //  noInterrupts ();  // atomic change of the time amount

   //In this area, we'll set the output pin to be used by the timing interrupt, 
   //and the time delay off the default waveform present on pin 4

   //We can use switch case arrangement, don't know if that's the optimal setup though    
 switch(incomingByte)
 {
   default:
   //Do Nothing
   break;

   //Cases FOR ALL THE LETTERS
   case 'a':
   break;
   case 'b':
   break;
   case 'c':
   break;
   case 'd':
   break;
   case 'e':
   break;
   case 'f':
   break;
   case 'g':
   break;
   case 'h':
   break;
   case 'i':
   break;
   case 'j':
   break;
   case 'k':
   break;
   case 'l':
   break;
   case 'm':
   break;
   case 'n':
   break;
   case 'o':
   break;
   case 'p':
   break;
   case 'q':
   break;
   case 'r':
   //Output pin 17 Frequency Pin 10
   //microseconds
   timerhigh=8000;
   waveout=9;
   break;
   case 's':
   break;
   case 't':
   break;
   case 'u':
   break;
   case 'v':
   break;
   case 'w':
   break;
   case 'x':
   break;
   case 'y':
   break;
   case 'z':
   break;

   //Cases FOR ALL THE NUMBERS
   case '0':
   break;
   case '1':
   break;
   case '2':
   break;
   case '3':
   break;
   case '4':
   break;
   case '5':
   break;
   case '6':
   break;
   case '7':
   break;
   case '8':
   break;
   case '9':
   break;

   //Cases FOR ALL THE PUNCTUATION
   case '.':
   break;
   case ',':
   break;
   case '!':
   break;
   case '"':
   break;
   case '#':
   break;
   case '$':
   break;
   case '%':
   break;      
 }

//Enables Rising Interrupt for 0ms detection
//attachInterrupt(1,rising,RISING);

//Reenables interrupts after offset time change
//interrupts ();
}
```

Comment: Which MCU? What clock frequency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that timer 0 and 2 on the arduino uno are 8 bit. Set a different prescaler and I'm golden

```
// set up Timer 2
    TCCR2A = 0;  // normal mode
    TCCR2B = 0;
    //  TCCR2A = bit(WGM21) | bit(CS21);  // CTC, scale to clock / 8
    TCCR2A = (1 << WGM21); //Enables CTC for timer 

    TCCR2B |= (1 << CS21); 
    TCCR2B |= (1 << CS22); //Sets 256 bit prescaler
    TCCR2B |= (0 << CS20); 
    OCR2A = groundtime;    // time before rising edge
    TIMSK2 = (1 << OCIE2A);
    //Cancel Rising Interrupt on D3
    EIFR = bit (INTF1); 
    //Reinables interrupts
```